# Signal R how properly take data from events?

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr

My problem is: I subscribed to events in signalR, but I don’t understand how to correctly take the data from this answer and put it in UI. The documentation shows the same method as in my code, but an empty list is returned to me in the user interface. In my case i get the data at the moment when the event comes, until i get the data from the event the list is empty and i thought to capture this data somehow, because i have to show it to the user. But the data from the event is not coming to my UI

But there is data in the console. Here they are - `[{warpedBox: [604.3993, 290.7302, 1106.364, 290.7302, 1106.364, 530.2628, 604.3993, 530.2628], name: Cats, date: 2022-09-05T09:01:11.9003992+03:00, additionInfo: new animal detected, baseName: TestBase, imageGuid: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}]` . How to get data from an event?

*Many thanks to Robert Sandberg*

I made some changes and now my code is like that (also I added UI part, because I don't understand how to make it work)

My code is now:

```
typedef CallbackFunc = void Function(List<dynamic>? arguments);
 

   class Animals {
      Alarmplayer alarmplayer = Alarmplayer();
    
      Future<void> fetchAnimals(CallbackFunc arguments) async {
        final httpConnectionOptions = HttpConnectionOptions(
            accessTokenFactory: () => SharedPreferenceService().loginWithToken(),
            skipNegotiation: true,
            transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets);
        final hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(
              'secure_link',
              options: httpConnectionOptions,
            )
            .build();
        await hubConnection.start();
        hubConnection.on('Animals', (arguments);
 alarmplayer.Alarm(url: 'assets/wanted.mp3', volume: 0.01);
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2))
              .then((value) => alarmplayer.StopAlarm());
        });
      }
     return agruments
    }
```

My UI-part:

```
  class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: FutureBuilder<void>(
///can't understand how to pass here arguments
              future: fetchAnimals(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(children: [
                      Text(snapshot.data?[index]['name']),
                    ]);
                  },
                );
              }),
```

I am sorry but I am really noob in that and can't understand how can I use it in the UI

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you mean that you get an empty list where you do the `print(detectedAnimals );` ? With this setup, your method will basically always return an empty list.

And that is because your method have already executed that print line (and the return statement) when you get the event over SignalR.

The callback you send into the hubConnection must have a way to report back to the UI, meaning it have to have a way to communicate back to the method that is calling `fetchAnimals()` WHEN the callback is executed.

So I'd inject the callback into `fetchAnimals()` as such:

```
typedef CallbackFunc = void Function(List<dynamic>? arguments);

Future<void> fetchAnimals(CallbackFunc callback) async {
....
  hubConnection.on('Animals', callback);
...
}
```

Comment: oh, thanks you. yes, in my case i get the data at the moment when the event comes, until i get the data from the event the list is empty and i thought to capture this data somehow, because i have to show it to the user. But the data from the event is not coming to my UI

Comment: Yes, the callback that you send into the `.on('Animals', ....)` is the thing that is executed when the event comes. So it is that callback that have to provide your UI with the correct information.

Comment: thanks. can I ask another question? Should I use futurebuilder or it is better to use sreams for such task?

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to say that it depends what you want to do with the information from the callback. Just try and see what works best for you.

Comment: I found the issue. Backend developers set a very large timeout, so when a value came in, this value did not have time to write to my variable. After the developers set a small timeout, the value was displayed and I was able to manipulate the data as I want. I also declared a global variable and write the value from the event there

Comment: Yeah well that global variable that you write to is a simplified (and perhaps a bad version) of what I wrote above. The key thing is that the callback have to report to the UI. As I wrote above... That timeout shouldn't change anything. As soon as backend have fired the event, the information is sent to you...